# Respaldo de servidor de BD postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

tengo un problema yo realice un backup del servidor donde tenia las bace de datos de las app el cual se creo en un .sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora intento restaurar el respaldo de forma tradicional y no me deja!!
dice que tiene que ser un formato tipo .backup

use el comando : `psql -U usuario -d basededatos -p 5432 -h 192.168.0.111 < fichero.sql`
tambien el : `psql -h localhost -d userstoreis -U admin -p 5432 -a -q -f /home/jobs/Desktop/resources/postgresql.sql`
y no hace nada , no se si tiene que estar en una carpeta especifica para que funcione la restauracion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien tengo la carpeta var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/base , donde esta guardada la BD , podria mover esa carpeta al nuevo server de postgres y recuperar la BD , es que ya no puedo hacer otro backup de la anterior BD

Comment: quieres hacer el restore? el comando es diferente `#psql -U usuario -d basededatos -p 5432 -h 192.168.0.111  -f fichero.sql`

Comment: ese comando tambien lo he usuado pero igual no hace nada!! yo estoy en una maquina windows

Comment: deberias agregar el comando que usaste para el respaldo

Comment: estas seguro que bajaste un archivo de backup y no un archivo que contiene solo las estructuras? que tipo de cosas tiene tu archivo sql?

Comment: el archivo contiene querys para la creación de las bd y los datos que esta contenia

Comment: eso es un pg_dump, por lo tanto tienes que hacer un pg_restore `pg_restore -d basededatos  /home/jobs/Desktop/resources/postgresql.sql -c -U ùsuario`

Answer (score 1):

Segun la documentación de [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-psql.html), la consola de `windows` utiliza una codificación diferente a la de tu sistema, por tanto al utilizar caracteres de 8 bits salta una advertencia.

Para cambiar la codificación de la consola tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
cmd.exe /c chcp 65001
```

que codifia a `utf-8`. Si necesitas utilizar otro código visita [Windows Encoding Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8)

Y cambiar la fuente de la consola a `Lucida Console`

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: use el comando psql -U username -d database_name -f /objects.sql y me funciono solo que tuve que hacerlo desde el mismo servidor linux por que remoto desde windows no daba respuesta